# Building Google Talk (aka. WebRTC) PeerConnection Example

Tags: webrtc, google-talk, libjingle

The WebRTC library [getting started guide](https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/reference/getting-started) explains how to compile the library.

The sample programs in `./trunk/talk/examples/peerconnection` are not built, however, and there are no make files in those directories to do this.

Can someone explain how to compile this, and perhaps the other Talk example programs on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to build them using the [ninja](http://martine.github.io/ninja/) build tool. I don't know if building using `make` is supported as well.

When you've checked out the code, you should have subdirectories `trunk/out/Debug` and `trunk/out/Release`. In them, there should be `build.ninja` files. Just go to one of those directories and type `ninja` to start the build. The peerconnection executables will be `peerconnection_client` and `peerconnection_server` in the Debug or Release directory.

In case the ninja build files need to be regenerated, you can execute `gyp_webrtc` from the `trunk/webrtc/build` subirectory